# How to configure Python with M$ Forefront (TMG) proxy

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, proxy, pip

I'm trying to use Python 3.7  and PIP (on Windows 7) behind corporate firewall but I'm getting following error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed:
407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywin32/
```

I've tried following configurations to pass proxy access and anyone of these is not working :(

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\user:pass@proxyhost:port`

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxyhost:port`

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyhost:port`

[image: Proxy error in PyCharm]

Comment: Most likely the corporate firewall is blocking PIP you can't fix it yourself (happened to me several times in the past).  You need to ask for permission to pip install whatever it is you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my organization proxy auth too and was getting 407 errors in Windows OS, finally solved it using [CTNLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) , so first try to config ctnlm for your proxy and test it with your browser (the config is located in %PROGRAMFILES%\Cntlm\cntlm.ini for windows and default proxy should be something like http://localhost:3128) and if it worked give it to pip install : `--proxy http://localhost:3128`